# Generating a new List from two Separate Lists with one Line of Code

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying an exercise that requires you to:

> write a program that returns a list that contains only the elements
> that are common between the lists (without duplicates). Make sure your
> program works on two lists of different sizes.

I was able to do this, but one of the extra challenges is to:

> Write this in one line of Python

I came up with the following code:

```
list_1 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 89]
list_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 3, 3, 13]
newList = []

newList = [x for x in list_1 if x in list_2 if x not in newList] #attempting one line

print(newList)
newList = []

for x in list_1:
    if x in list_2 and x not in newList:
        newList.append(x)

print(newList)
```

I get the following results:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

My single-line list comprehension seems to fail, can someone point out why that is?

Comment: `list(set(list_1) & set(list_2))`…?

Comment: The list comprehension fails because `newList` doesn't contain any elements until the comprehension is complete and the result is assigned to `newList`. It's always equivalent to `... if x not in []`.

Comment: Well, the cheap way is `newList = list(set(list_1).intersection(set(list_2)))`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I see what the issue is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic approach would be to cast newList to set and then recast it to list

```
print(list(set(newList)))
```

Or by using set intersection without any loops

```
print(list(set(list_1).intersection(list_2)))
```